# create function "find" like notepad vb.net

Tags: vb.net, notepad

my user request a program to show data from mapping. 
example \IP\st\ng\ej\txt1.txt
and then all lines at txt1.txt, move to richtextbox or textbox. and then user would like **looking for** something like number or whatever user wants.
im already researched at google, and mostly just give "sign" like font color or back color changes.
please any help, any referense
thanks

Comment: After you find where the text is, just change the selected text property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try InStr() function, like this:

```
Private Sub buttonfind.click(...)
        Dim pos As Integer
        pos = InStr(1, txtnote.Text, textboxfind.Text)
        If pos > 0 Then 'If found test
            txtNote.SelectionStart = pos - 1
            txtNote.SelectionLength = Len(tlstSearch.Text)
            txtNote.Focus()  'Get Focus
        End If
End Sub
```

txtnote is store all text in the richtextbox or textbox.

textboxfind is store text your want to find.

buttonfind is command button.

[MSDN referense for InStr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx)